# In linux, how can I zip specific sub directories into their own zip files named parent directory name and output them all into a single directory?

Tags: linux, bash, zip

So I have seen similar questions that answer part of my question, but not to the specific level I'm needing. Here is the overall gist of what I'm trying to do.

I am migrating a bunch of websites to a new server. Currently, they are all located in `/srv/www/`

Each site has its own folder in that directory name after the domain such as `/srv/www/domain1.com`, `/srv/www/domain2.com`.

And in each `domain.com` directory there is the public web directory named `html`.

What I want to do is cd into `/srv/www` then run a command or bash script that will recurrsivly go into each `domain.com/html` directory and zip the contents of that directory, then output it as a zip name `domain.com.zip` in `/srv/web_backup/domain.com.zip`. Again, I only want the contents. When I unzip the file, I don't want it to output into `html/{contents}`.

In this case, `domain.com` is an example, but each folder will have its own name.

If I were manually doing this, once I cd into `/srv/www/domain.com/html` I would run the command `zip -r /srv/web_backup/domain.com.zip . .htaccess` and that is what I want to run to get all files, directories, and the .htaccess file.

So to summarize, I want to individually zip the contents, not the directory, of every `/srv/www/{domain.com}/html` and have them named `{domain.com}.zip` (the parent directory of the `html` folder) and then save those zip files to `/srv/web_backup/domain.com.zip`

I appreciate any help as I'm not too humble to admit this is above my Linux knowledge or ability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've mostly described the steps. You just need to put them into a script. Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /srv/www
for domain in *; do
(
cd $domain/html &&
zip -r /srv/web_backup/$domain.zip . .htaccess
)
done
```

Breaking that down a bit:

```
# change into the /srv/www directory
cd /srv/www

# for each domain in this directory (we're largely assuming here that
# this directory contains only directories representing domains you
# want to backup).
for domain in *; do

# a (...) expression runs the included commands in a subshell, so
# that when we exit we're back in /srv/www.
(
# change into the html directory and, if that was successful, update
# your zip file.
cd $domain/html &&
zip -r /srv/web_backup/$domain.zip .
)

done
```

This is only one way of tackling this particular problem. You could also write something like:

```
#!/bin/sh

find /srv/www/* -maxdepth 0 -type d -print0 |
xargs -0 -iDOMAIN sh -c 'cd "DOMAIN/html" && zip -r "/srv/www/DOMAIN.zip" .
```

That does roughly the same thing, but makes clever use of `find` and `xargs`.

Comment: So far this looks great, however, 2 things:
1) There is more than just the html directory in the domain folder. There is also /logs and other dirs.
2) Does you script find all folders or do I have to provide a list of the domain directories?

EDIT: Nevermind, did a test by echoing $domain and I see what you did now. This might work perfectly. I will report back after a test.

Comment: I'm running the script now. Took a peak in a couple of the zip files created and so far it all looks great!!! I will report back once completed, but I think there is an "Accepted Answer" in your future. Thank you so much @larsks

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you again!